# React-Table doesnt show data from Firebase

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I tried to retrieve data from firebase real time db into the react-table as given in [this stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/). I do get the table but I am not getting any data from firebase in the table. Console shows nothing as such.

My firebase real time db structure is like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7jX8h.png).

Below is my code TablePages.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactTable from "react-table";
import "react-table/react-table.css";
import firebase from 'firebase/app';
// import 'firebase/auth';
import 'firebase/database';
import '../../firebase'


export default class LockTable extends Component {
  state = { data: [] };

  componentDidMount() {
    const database = firebase.database().ref("/Assets");
    database.on("value", snapshot => {
      const data = [];

      snapshot.forEach(childSnapShot => {
        const asset = {
          AssetNumber: childSnapShot.key.toString(),
          GivenBy: childSnapShot.val().GivenBy,
          TakenBy: childSnapShot.val().TakenBy
        };

        data.push(asset);
      });

      this.setState(prevState => {
        return { data: [...prevState.data, ...data] };
      });
    });
  }

  render() {
    const columns = [
      {
        Header: "Asset Number",
        accessor: "AssetNumber"
      },
      {
        Header: "Given By",
        accessor: "GivenBy"
      },
      {
        Header: "Taken By",
        accessor: "TakenBy"
      },

    ];

    return (
      <div>
        <ReactTable data={this.state.data} columns={columns} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Can anyone tell me which part has gone wrong?

Update: I updated Database structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
componentDidMount() {
    const database = firebase.database().ref("/Assets");
    database.on("value", async snapshot => {
      const data = [];

      await snapshot.forEach(childSnapShot => {
        const asset = {
          AssetNumber: childSnapShot.key.toString(),
          GivenBy: childSnapShot.val().GivenBy,
          TakenBy: childSnapShot.val().TakenBy
        };

        data.push(asset);
      });

      this.setState({data:[...this.state.data, ...data]});
    });
  }
```

Comment: @FranklinAntony answer updated. did you `console.log(data)` to make sure it returns anything

Comment: Nothing is shown in `console.log(data)` . I console logged at different stages and found that It is not going beyond the first line inside `componentDidMount()` . So something is wrong when calling `.ref("/Assets")` .
I will update DB structure. [DB Updated]